# Code to include link list content in search not working

Tags: sxa, sxa-search, computed-field

I contacted Sitecore Support for the issue and this was the solution given.  Our website has a lot of link lists throughout the site.  We noticed that link lists are not being searched (the link text), so I was told I needed to extend the `AggregatedContent.cs` class and add a config file to add it to my website.  The class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Layouts;
using Sitecore.Text;

namespace BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search
{
    public class AggregatedContent : Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent
    {
        protected override IEnumerable<Item> GetLayoutReferences(Item item, ISet<Item> dataFolders)
        {
            LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(item);
            using (new ContextItemSwitcher(item))
            {
                DeviceItem[] all = item.Database.Resources.Devices.GetAll();
                foreach (DeviceItem device in all)
                {
                    IEnumerable<RenderingReference> references = layoutField.GetReferences(device);
                    foreach (RenderingReference item3 in references ?? Enumerable.Empty<RenderingReference>())
                    {
                        string[] items = new ListString(item3.Settings.DataSource ?? string.Empty).Items;
                        foreach (string path in items)
                        {
                            Item item2 = item.Database.GetItem(path, item.Language, Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest);
                            if (item2 != null && IsDataItem(item2, dataFolders))
                            {
                                // custom - start
                                if (item2.TemplateName == "Link List")
                                {
                                    foreach (Item linkItem in item2.Children)
                                    {
                                        var field = (LinkField)linkItem.Fields["Link"];
                                        if (field.IsInternal)
                                        {
                                            yield return field.TargetItem;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // custom - end
                                yield return item2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch search:require="solr">
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
          <documentOptions>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="sxacontent">
                <patch:delete />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="sxacontent" returnType="textCollection" type="BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search.AggregatedContent, BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search">
                <mediaIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing"/>
              </field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I've checked showconfig.aspx to make sure this code is being included and it is.  I rebuilt my indexes, and the link lists are still not showing up when I search the text of one of the links.

Comment: Hello, are you sure that your field tag in the configuration is correct?

Comment: Did you try to debug this code due to reindex?

Comment: @VadimBirkos How can I debug a class library with Sitecore?  And I'm not sure if the field tag is correct but it's what Sitecore Support gave me.  What part of it do you think I might need to change?

Comment: As I understood  BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search.AggregatedContent contains in your solution and you can check if the crawler reached this place due Re-Index.  
Here instructions how to Debug not your DLLs in Visual Studio. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654696/how-to-debug-external-class-library-projects-in-visual-studio

Comment: Alright, so I just need to put a stop on my code in my class.  Do I need to do a reindex to hit it or just search for something?  Sorry I got this code from Sitecore Support and am not entirely sure what it does.

Comment: @OliviaShettles Did you check your sxacontent value in solr having the links value that are getting indexed? Check the value in solr dashboard

Comment: @Sreekrishnan Hi I did check that.  They are not showing up :/

Comment: @OliviaShettles yes, you need to add stop into code and run re-index then. Because it's a ComputedIndexField

Comment: Does your component contain values in the link list field?

Comment: @VadimBirkos You are so helpful.  I was able to debug the DLL and it is being hit while I am reindexing.  My component does contain values in the link list field.

Comment: @VadimBirkos Do you know of any cases where people have been able to index link list text as sxacontent?  If there are any links to pages within the site, those are being indexed.  However, let's say the text of the link is "Test" but the title of the page that it links to is "Search", it will index the word search rather than test. Links to files and external links are not being indexed at all, even if I remove the if statement to check if internal (it thows an exception trying to index them).

Comment: I think it rare case but it's exactly possible. You should return through yield return your item that contains the value and exists as an internal Sitecore Link. I prefer to move to the chat. Because a lot of comments here. I am sure that your issue can be resolved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121055/discussion-between-vadim-birkos-and-olivia-shettles).